# Calling a function in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
// Explicit global
$.fn.getRedemptionID = function(){
window.varMy = data.DATA[0].item1;
}
```

How do you call the above function to get the variable varMy ?

Comment: That sets `varMy`, it doesn't get it.

Comment: Is this really the code ? It creates a global variable varMy, when invoked on a jquery object ? What's data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you previous question, I think you basically want the var to be returned to the calling part.. then you can write as below,

```
$.fn.getRedemptionID = function(){
   return data.DATA[0].item1;
}
```

and to call,

```
var myVar = $(selector).getRedemptionID();
```

Comment: I get $("#messageText").getRedemptionID is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Functions attached to `$.fn` are jQuery plugins.  They needs to be called on a jQuery object.

For example:

```
$('#myDiv').getRedemptionID();
```

Comment: so I need the plug-in to use fn?

Comment: @Spike Tell us what you are writing. Are you creating a jQuery plugin.. or a simple method that process something and sets the variable.

Comment: @Spike: You don't *need* a plug-in, you are creating one.